# Is $y=20-bx^2$ a linear equation or not?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I encountered this question in a textbook and l am a bit confused.

Linear equations are all equations where the highest degree of the expression is 1 but l want to know whether there are other forms of linear equations.

> Consider $y=20-bx^2$ where $y$ is a function of $x^2$. Will this also be a linear equation even though it is a second degree expression? Does it make a difference if I say $y$ is a function of $x^2$ instead of $x$  .

Comment: No, this is not a linear function because, as you said, the highest degree of the expression is not 1. However, this is a quadratic function.

Comment: @Nicholas Roberts, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a linear equation with respect to $x^2$. It is a non-linear(quadratic) with respect to $x$.

You cannot define linearity without defining what element you choose to see the variation. Even $y=sin(x)$ is linear with respect to $sin(x)$, or $y=x$ is non linear with respect to $\sqrt x$

The word itself refers to the graph of the function with respect to the variable you wish to see.

Conventionally, unless specifically mentioned, it is assumed that the function is with respect to $x$. So, if you give $y=20-x^2$, one would say that it is a quadratic equation. However, the correct statement should be - it is a quadratic equation with respect to $x$.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, l should have phrased my question a bit better.

Comment: It is linear in $b$, though.